# Rotating raster using Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, dem, rotate

I am trying to rotate a DEM raster (NetCDF file) using Python language, but there is still no progress. I have tried GDAL Python but not so much information in the document about rotation. Do you know how to do with gdal or any other modules/packages could execute this?

Answer (score 4):

You can rotate a raster using an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). Several packages can do this, including `gdal` (see [Raster API tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)) and `rasterio` (see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383781/172255) to [Defining Affine transform with rasterio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/383697/115)). However, the order of the parameters is not the same between the transformation function of `gdal` and that of `rasterio`, so be careful.

This code is a example of a rotation of raster with gdal (3.0.1) :

```py
from osgeo import gdal  # For read and manipulate rasters
from affine import Affine  # For easly manipulation of affine matrix


# Some functions declaration for clarify the code


def raster_center(raster):
    """This function return the pixel coordinates of the raster center 
    """

    # We get the size (in pixels) of the raster
    # using gdal
    width, height = raster.RasterXSize, raster.RasterYSize

    # We calculate the middle of raster
    xmed = width / 2
    ymed = height / 2

    return (xmed, ymed)


def rotate_gt(affine_matrix, angle, pivot=None):
    """This function generate a rotated affine matrix
    """

    # The gdal affine matrix format is not the same
    # of the Affine format, so we use a bullit-in function
    # to change it
    # see : https://github.com/sgillies/affine/blob/master/affine/__init__.py#L178
    affine_src = Affine.from_gdal(*affine_matrix)
    # We made the rotation. For this we calculate a rotation matrix,
    # with the rotation method and we combine it with the original affine matrix
    # Be carful, the star operator (*) is surcharged by Affine package. He make
    # a matrix multiplication, not a basic multiplication
    affine_dst = affine_src * affine_src.rotation(angle, pivot)
    # We retrun the rotated matrix in gdal format
    return affine_dst.to_gdal()


# Import the raster to rotate
# Here I use a sample of GDAL, dowloaded here : https://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/spot/chicago/SP27GTIF.TIF
# and transformed in nc with qgis
# NB: the transformation in nc is specific for the original question,
# this step is not neccecary if you copy/past this code
dataset_src = gdal.Open("SP27GTIF.NC")

# For no overwriting the original raster I make a copy

# I Get the reading/writing driver (GTIFF)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
# A new raster, the destination file, is created.
# This raster is a copy of the source raster (same size, values...)
datase_dst = driver.CreateCopy("SP27GTIF_rotate.TIF", dataset_src, strict=0)

# Now we can rotate the raster

# First step, we get the affine tranformation matrix of the initial fine
# More info here : https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html#geotransforms-tut
gt_affine = dataset_src.GetGeoTransform()

# Second we get the center of the raster to set the rotation center
# Be carefull, the center is in pixel number, not in projected coordinates
# More info on the  "raster_center" comment's
center = raster_center(dataset_src)

# Third we rotate the destination raster, datase_dst, with setting a new
# affine matrix made by the "rotate_gt" function.
# gt_affine is the initial affine matrix
# -33 is an exemple angle (in degrees)
# and center the center of raster
datase_dst.SetGeoTransform(rotate_gt(gt_affine, -33, center))
```

With this code you can rotate any raster. For example this image :

[image: The file to rotate]

Can be transformed in this one (after a -33° rotation)

[image: The SP27GTIF_rotate.TIF file, after a -33° rotation]