# Rotation of a spatial grid by an angle around a pivot with python gdal or rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, rotate

## What I want to do:

I have been trying to:

- Open a raster
- Make a copy
- Rotate the copy by an angle with the raster center as a pivot
- Keep the resolution constant in x/y dimension

## Solution 1 with gdal:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from optparse import OptionParser
import rasterio
from affine import Affine  # For easly manipulation of affine matrix
import scipy.ndimage
from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_raster, reshape_as_image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot


def get_center(dataset):
    """This function return the pixel coordinates of the raster center
    """
    # We get the size (in pixels) of the raster using gdal
    #width, height = raster.RasterXSize, raster.RasterYSize
    width, height = dataset.width, dataset.height
    # We calculate the middle of raster
    xmed = width // 2
    ymed = height // 2
    return (xmed, ymed)


def rotate_geotransform(affine_matrix, angle, pivot):
    """This function generate a rotated affine matrix
    """
    affine_dst = affine_matrix * affine_matrix.rotation(angle, pivot)
    return(affine_dst)


def rotate(inputRaster, angle, outputRaster=None):
    outputRaster = 'rotated.TIF' if outputRaster is None else outputRaster

    src_dataset = rasterio.open(inputRaster)
    # this is a 3D numpy array, with dimensions [band, row, col]
    Z = src_dataset.read()

    # raster rotation
    old_affine_matrix = src_dataset.transform
    pivot = get_center(src_dataset)
    new_affine_matrix = rotate_geotransform(old_affine_matrix, angle, pivot)

    # array rotation
    rotated_Z = scipy.ndimage.rotate(Z, angle, order=1, reshape=True, axes=(1,2), cval=np.nan)
    print(Z.shape)
    pyplot.imshow(reshape_as_image(Z))
    pyplot.show()
    print(rotated_Z.shape)
    pyplot.imshow(reshape_as_image(rotated_Z))
    pyplot.show()

    new_dataset = rasterio.open(
        outputRaster,
        'w',
        driver='GTiff',
        height=rotated_Z.shape[1],
        width=rotated_Z.shape[2],
        count=rotated_Z.shape[0],
        dtype=Z.dtype,
        crs=src_dataset.crs,
        transform=new_affine_matrix
    )
    new_dataset.write(rotated_Z)
    new_dataset.close()


def main(argv):
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", type="str", dest="output", help="Rotated output raster name")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return rotate(args[0], float(args[1]), options.output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

This seems to rotate the first figure into the second:
[image: raster 1]
[image: rotated raster by 60 degree]

## Problem of solution 1

I am not sure my code does exactly what I intend it to do. Visually it seems ok, but is the coordinate reference system correctly calculated?
It does not seem to keep the resolution constant (divided by appr. 2 in the rotated raster).

## Solution 2 with rasterio and Affine packages:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from optparse import OptionParser
import rasterio
from affine import Affine  # For easly manipulation of affine matrix
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
import numpy as np

def get_center(dataset):
    """This function return the pixel coordinates of the raster center
    """
    width, height = dataset.width, dataset.height
    # We calculate the middle of raster
    x_pixel_med = width // 2
    y_pixel_med = height // 2
    # The convention for the transform array as used by GDAL (T0) is to reference the pixel corner
    T0 = dataset.transform
    # We want to instead reference the pixel centre, so it needs to be translated by 50%:
    T1 = T0 * Affine.translation(0.5, 0.5)
    # to transform from pixel coordinates to world coordinates, multiply the coordinates with the matrix
    rc2xy = lambda r, c: T1 * (c, r)
    # get the coordinates for a raster in the first row, second column (index [0, 1]):
    return rc2xy(y_pixel_med, x_pixel_med)

def rotate(inputRaster, angle, outputRaster=None):
    outputRaster = 'rotated.tif' if outputRaster is None else outputRaster
    ### Read input
    source = rasterio.open(inputRaster)

    ### Rotate the affine
    pivot = get_center(source)
    pixel_size_x, pixel_size_y = source.res
    print("\nPivot coordinates:", pivot)
    new_transform = source.transform * Affine.rotation(angle, pivot) * Affine.scale(1)
    # this is a 3D numpy array, with dimensions [band, row, col]
    Z_source = source.read(masked=True)
    # Create destination raster
    destination = rasterio.open( outputRaster, 'w',
        driver='GTiff',
        height=source.height,
        width=source.width,
        count=source.count,
        crs=source.crs,
        dtype=Z_source.dtype,
        nodata=source.nodata,
        transform=new_transform)
    # Reproject pixels
    dst_shape = (destination.count, destination.height, destination.width)
    Z_destination = np.empty(dst_shape)
    Z_destination[:] = source.nodata

    reproject(
        Z_source,
        Z_destination,
        src_transform=source.transform,
        src_crs=source.crs,
        dst_transform=destination.transform,
        dst_crs=destination.crs,
        resampling=Resampling.average)

    destination.write(Z_destination)
    source.close()
    destination.close()
    return

def main(argv):
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", type="str", dest="output", help="Rotated output raster name")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return rotate(args[0], float(args[1]), options.output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

But somehow, the rotation seems to send the raster quite far, so I guess there is a bug with the code that should use the raster center cell as a pivot. However, I can't find what my mistake is.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the ```reshape``` parameter of the ```scipy.ndimage.rotate``` function. We can see in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html) that this parameter changes the resolution of the image so that it keeps the same number of rows and columns. However I don't understand why you use the ```rotate``` function to perform the rotation, you can do it directly [with rasterio](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/1420#issue-344001299) or [gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408396/172255).

Comment: Thank you for you information about the reshape parameter. 
I did try to use rasterio and gdal (in the last case using the same resources you pointed to). But I did not succeed to visualize them rotated, and somehow that's how I ended up using the `rotate` function. If will try to use the [rasterio issue](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/1420#issue-344001299) you linked to and come back if I can't do any progress.

Comment: @Atm I came with a code that uses rasterio (see Solution 2)! But my pivot seems off :( Any idea of what I got wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it working using rasterio. The problem was that the Affine pivot parameter is actually in pixel coordinates, and I was passing real world coordinates. So few lines of code later, this is rotating as exected!

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from optparse import OptionParser
import rasterio
from affine import Affine  # For easly manipulation of affine matrix
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
import numpy as np

def get_center_pixel(dataset):
    """This function return the pixel coordinates of the raster center
    """
    width, height = dataset.width, dataset.height
    # We calculate the middle of raster
    x_pixel_med = width // 2
    y_pixel_med = height // 2
    return (x_pixel_med, y_pixel_med)

def rotate(inputRaster, angle, scale=1, outputRaster=None):
    outputRaster = 'rotated.tif' if outputRaster is None else outputRaster

    ### Read input
    source = rasterio.open(inputRaster)
    assert source.crs == 'EPSG:4326', "Raster must have CRS=EPSG:4326, that is unprojected lon/lat (degree) relative to WGS84 datum"

    ### Rotate the affine about a pivot and rescale
    pivot = get_center_pixel(source)
    #pivot = None
    print("\nPivot coordinates:", source.transform * pivot)
    new_transform = source.transform * Affine.rotation(angle, pivot) * Affine.scale(scale)

    # this is a 3D numpy array, with dimensions [band, row, col]
    data = source.read(masked=True)
    kwargs = source.meta
    kwargs['transform'] = new_transform

    with rasterio.open(outputRaster, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, source.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(source, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=source.transform,
                src_crs=source.crs,
                dst_transform=new_transform,
                dst_crs=dst.crs,
                resampling=Resampling.average)
    return

def main(argv):
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", type="str", dest="output", help="Rotated output raster name")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return rotate(args[0], float(args[1]), float(args[2]), options.output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```