# Rotate shapefile based on raster coordinates using Python

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, rotate

I have a shapefile with polygons and a raster file.
I know the coordinates of raster file corners and also the coordinates of shape file polygon files.

What I need to do, is rotate/transform the polygon based on raster corners, so that result is the polygon and raster placed in the same direction, **precisely**.

This probably could be done using simple math and figuring out the angle of rotation, however, I could not come up with any solution.

Let's say that I need to rotate the figure using point `A`, as it stays the same. How can I calculate the right angles and actually rotate the figure using Python?

Here is a solution on how to rotate images using the centre point and angle [Rotating raster using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408386/rotating-raster-using-python), in this case, I somehow have to get the angle first using a raster image and then rotate polygon.

Here is how I got the coordinates for raster:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rasterio

src =rasterio.open(r'W:\raster.tif')
print("The CRS of this data is:", src.crs)
print(src.bounds)

# The CRS of this data is: EPSG:32635
# BoundingBox(left=399960.0, bottom=6290220.0, right=509760.0, top=6400020.0)

# shapefile coordinates

shape_file = r'W:\shapefile.shp'
shape = gpd.read_file(shape_file)
print(shape.crs)
# epsg:32635

vector = ogr.Open(shape_file)
layer = vector.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
vectorGeometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
(minX, maxX, minY, maxY) = vectorGeometry.GetEnvelope()

 # 422584.5923673369688913,484834.5028625923441723 6334526.4352870080620050 6374438.1786635806784034
```

[image]

Example on how the rotation result would look like with more than one polygon:
[image]

Why this is crucial? Well, because if shapefile polygons are not rotated based on raster coordinates and placement, later on when I do the clipping part on raster, the result is this, which is not what I need:

This is because polygon corner coordinates do not correspond to raster corner coordinated, creating this error, even though I specify source and destination crs running gdal.Warp like this:

```
         cut = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = fname_out, 
                         srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = image_path,
                         srcSRS = 'EPSG:32635',
                         dstSRS='EPSG:32635',
                         outputBounds     = (minx, miny, maxx, maxy),
                         cropToCutline    = True,
                         copyMetadata     = True)

         cut=None
```

[image]

Comment: No, there are about 10 polygons. I created this one as an example

Comment: they should be rotated all the same, as the raster image is only one and doesn't change. I assumed that if I know the angle from th raster, I could rotate all of them the same

Comment: no, i added an example of how the rotation would look with more than one polygon. all the same