# GDAL: Projecting a raster in 3 dimensions

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to project the 2D result of transforming a raster in 3 dimensions (using yaw pitch and roll) with GDAL.

From [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408386/rotating-raster-using-python) answer, I've been able to successfully rotate a raster around its center point in 2 dimensions using 3x3 affine transformations provided by the python [affine library](https://pypi.org/project/affine/).

Is there a way to extend this fully into 3 dimensions and transform a raster with the top down view of the 3D transformation? The solution doesn't necessarily need to involve GDAL or python.

Some background context:

When generating rasters and 3D models using photogrammetry software, the resultant outputs are not always aligned to satellite imagery. I can transform the 3D model to match satellite imagery easily enough but struggling to do this for the 2D raster.